# strong and em markups don't display correctly

Tags: asp.net, css, telerik

I've got this div:

```
<div class="fieldFullTextReadOnly">
  <span style="color: #ff0000;">
    <strong>bold test</strong>
  </span>
  <span style="color: #ffc000;">
    <em>italic test</em>
  </span>
</div>
```

The relevant css:

```
.fieldFullTextReadOnly {
    color: #167F78;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

In Firebug, it shows that the color is overridden, which is right:

[image]

But neither the `<strong>` nor the `<em>` are applied, and the text keeps being displayed with a normal weight.

What is happening ? And what can I change to display the text with the right font weight ?

The div inner HTML is generated by the Telerik text editor, so I can't change anything here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Used to this way**

```
.fieldFullTextReadOnly  strong{font-weight:bold;}
.fieldFullTextReadOnly em{font-style:italic;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set the text to a normal `font-weight`.
Add this below your CSS:

```
.fieldFullTextReadOnly strong {
    font-weight:bold;
}
.fieldFullTextReadOnly em {
    font-style:italic;
}
```